# Access 2007 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Connection issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an app with Access 2007 form connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database
sometimes when a lot of users connecting at the same time there are error happened that "they can't connect to DB now", if I restart the server the problem vanishes!

When one user uses the app no problem happens. Here under the VB code please check it and tell me if there any problem and how shall I solve the concurrency problem on SQL Server ?

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'--------------------------------- check Nullbility
If IsNull([AD]) = True Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Log Out & Log in again", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            Exit Sub
            End If
 If IsNull([Cisco]) = True Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Enter the Agent`s Cisco", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[Cisco]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
  If IsNull([JustificationType]) = True Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Choose the Justification Type from List", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[JustificationType]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
  If IsNull([Just]) = True Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Choose the Justification from List", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[Just]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
  If IsNull([fromdate]) = True Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Enter the DateOfCase", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[fromdate]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
   If IsNull([todate]) = True And Me.JustificationType = "Absent" And Me.Just <> "Move Off" Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
             MsgBox "Enter Justification`s ""End Date """, vbInformation, "Missing Date!"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[todate]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
  If IsNull([OldOff]) = True And Me.JustificationType = "Absent" And Me.Just = "Move Off" Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
             MsgBox "Enter Agent`s Old Off", vbInformation, "Missing Date!"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[OldOff]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
 If IsNull([Approved]) = True Or [Approved] = "------Select From The List------" Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Choose the Name from the List", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[Approved]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
'---------------------------------From Date < To Date Event
  If ([fromdate] > [todate]) Then
            Beep
            MsgBox "Recheck again as the ""End Date "" before ""Start Date """, vbInformation, "  Wrong Vacation!"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[fromdate]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
  If IsNull([FromEv]) = True And JustificationType = "Event" Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "You Must Specify ""Start"" Time", vbExclamation, "Missing AuthOriginal_Shift_LBLzed Time"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[FromEv]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
 If IsNull([ToEv]) = True And JustificationType = "Event" Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "You Must Specify ""End"" Time", vbExclamation, "Missing AuthOriginal_Shift_LBLzed Time"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[ToEv]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
   If IsNull([AgentShift]) = True And JustificationType = "Event" Then
   If Me.Just <> "Move Shift" Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "Enter Agent`s Shift", vbExclamation, "Missing Data"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[agentshift]"
            Exit Sub
            End If
            End If





Dim TTCount As Long
Dim FirstTTID As Long
Dim FirstATTID As Long
Dim MoveOff As Variant
Dim Minute_Duration As Long
Dim String_Minute_Duration As String
Dim destinationFile As String
Dim aFSO As Variant

Dim con As Object
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim ParCisco As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParDate_Of_Case As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParMove_Off As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParAgentShift As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParFrom As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParTo As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParEvent_Duration As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParCredit_Hours As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParDebit_Hours As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParJustification As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParDescription As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParCreator As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParApproved_By As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParType As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Par_MaxGroupID_Out As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParFile_Ext As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParOriginal_Path As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParNew_Path As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Justification_MaxID_OUT As ADODB.Parameter
Dim ParAttachment_MaxID_Out As ADODB.Parameter

Dim Justification_Cisco As Long
Dim Justification_Date_Of_Case As Variant
Dim Justification_Move_Off As Variant
Dim Justification_AgentShift As String
Dim Justification_From As String
Dim Justification_To As String
Dim Justification_Event_Duration As Long
Dim Justification_Credit_Hours As Long
Dim Justification_Debit_Hours As Long
Dim Justification_Justification As String
Dim Justification_Description As String
Dim Justification_Creator As String
Dim Justification_Approved_By As String
Dim Justification_Type As String
Dim Var_MaxGroupID As Long
Dim JustificationMaxID As Long
Dim AttachmentMaxID As Long




'---------------------------------event duration Time < 23:00 Hours
If Me.JustificationType = "Absent" = True Then
Justification_Event_Duration = 0
Else
Minute_Duration = DateDiff("S", Me.FromEv, Me.ToEv, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)
        If (Minute_Duration > 82800) Then
            DoCmd.CancelEvent
            Beep
            MsgBox "The Event Duration Must be less than 23:00 Hours", vbInformation, "Wrong Duration Time"
            DoCmd.GoToControl "[FromEv]"
            Exit Sub
            End If

Justification_Event_Duration = Abs(Minute_Duration)
End If
'------------------------------------------------------------------

Justification_Cisco = Me.Cisco
Justification_Date_Of_Case = Me.fromdate
Justification_Justification = Me.Just
Justification_Creator = Me.AD
Justification_Approved_By = Me.Approved
Justification_Type = Me.JustificationType



If (Me.Just = "Leave Early(Credit Hour)") Then
Justification_Credit_Hours = Abs(DateDiff("S", Me.FromEv, Me.ToEv, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) * 0.75)
Else
Justification_Credit_Hours = 0
End If

If (Me.Just = "Over Time(Debit Hours)") Then
Justification_Debit_Hours = Abs(DateDiff("S", Me.FromEv, Me.ToEv, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem))
Else
Justification_Debit_Hours = 0
End If

If IsNull([FromEv]) = True Then
Justification_From = "00:00:00"
Else
Justification_From = Me.FromEv
End If
If IsNull([ToEv]) = True Then
Justification_To = "00:00:00"
Else
Justification_To = Me.ToEv
End If
If IsNull([AgentShift]) = True Then
Justification_AgentShift = "00:00:00"
Else
Justification_AgentShift = Me.AgentShift
End If
If IsNull([Description]) = True Then
Justification_Description = "Null"
Else
Justification_Description = Me.Description
End If
If IsNull([OldOff]) = True Then
Justification_Move_Off = "1-1-2010"
Else
Justification_Move_Off = Me.OldOff
End If
If ([Just] = "Move Off" And Me.JustificationType = "Absent") Then
TTCount = 1
End If
If ([Just] <> "Move Off" And Me.JustificationType = "Absent") Then
TTCount = [Forms]![Justification]![Count]
End If
If (Me.JustificationType = "Event") Then
TTCount = 1
End If



'Get Max Group ID By Procedure  ----------------------------------------


    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open _
            "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=192.168.4.96;Initial Catalog=ZainJTA;User Id=JTAUser;Password=.369*-+MK;"

             Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = con
  .CommandText = "[dbo].[SP_Justification_Max_Group_ID]"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    Set Par_MaxGroupID_Out = .CreateParameter("@Just_Out_MaxGroupID", _
      adInteger, adParamOutput)
  .Parameters.Append Par_MaxGroupID_Out
  .Execute
End With
'Get justification and Attachment IDs ----------------------------------------
Var_MaxGroupID = Par_MaxGroupID_Out.Value

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing



'Loop  ----------------------------------------
For Justification_Insert = 1 To TTCount

    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    con.Open _
            "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=192.168.4.96;Initial Catalog=ZainJTA;User Id=JTAUser;Password=.369*-+MK;"
             Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

 ' Execute SQL Procedure to Insert Data into SQL Server DB

With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = con
  .CommandText = "[dbo].[SP_Justification_Insert]"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

  Set ParCisco = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Cisco", _
      adInteger, adParamInput, 10, Justification_Cisco)
  .Parameters.Append ParCisco
    Set ParDate_Of_Case = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Date_Of_Case", _
      adDate, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Date_Of_Case)
  .Parameters.Append ParDate_Of_Case
      Set ParMove_Off = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Move_Off", _
      adDate, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Move_Off)
  .Parameters.Append ParMove_Off
    Set ParAgentShift = .CreateParameter("@Justification_AgentShift", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_AgentShift)
  .Parameters.Append ParAgentShift
    Set ParFrom = .CreateParameter("@Justification_From", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_From)
  .Parameters.Append ParFrom
    Set ParTo = .CreateParameter("@Justification_To", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_To)
  .Parameters.Append ParTo
      Set ParEvent_Duration = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Event_Duration", _
      adInteger, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Event_Duration)
  .Parameters.Append ParEvent_Duration
    Set ParCredit_Hours = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Credit_Hours", _
      adInteger, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Credit_Hours)
  .Parameters.Append ParCredit_Hours
      Set ParDebit_Hours = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Debit_Hours", _
      adInteger, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Debit_Hours)
  .Parameters.Append ParDebit_Hours
    Set ParJustification = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Justification", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Justification)
  .Parameters.Append ParJustification
    Set ParDescription = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Description", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Description)
  .Parameters.Append ParDescription
    Set ParCreator = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Creator", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Creator)
  .Parameters.Append ParCreator
    Set ParApproved_By = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Approved_By", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Approved_By)
  .Parameters.Append ParApproved_By
    Set ParType = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Type", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Justification_Type)
  .Parameters.Append ParType
    Set ParGroup_ID = .CreateParameter("@Justification_Group_ID", _
      adInteger, adParamInput, 255, Var_MaxGroupID)
  .Parameters.Append ParGroup_ID
    Set ParFile_Ext = .CreateParameter("@Attachament_File_Ext", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, TempVars!FileExt)
  .Parameters.Append ParFile_Ext
    Set ParOriginal_Path = .CreateParameter("@Attachament_Original_Path", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, TempVars!SourceFile)
  .Parameters.Append ParOriginal_Path
    Set ParNew_Path = .CreateParameter("@Attachament_New_Path", _
      adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, Null)
  .Parameters.Append ParNew_Path
  Set ParJustification_MaxID_OUT = .CreateParameter("@Justification_MaxID_OUT", _
      adInteger, adParamOutput)
  .Parameters.Append ParJustification_MaxID_OUT
    Set ParAttachment_MaxID_Out = .CreateParameter("@Attachment_MaxID_Out", _
      adInteger, adParamOutput)
  .Parameters.Append ParAttachment_MaxID_Out

  .Execute
End With
'Get justification and Attachment IDs ----------------------------------------

JustificationMaxID = ParJustification_MaxID_OUT.Value
AttachmentMaxID = ParAttachment_MaxID_Out.Value

If (Justification_Insert) = 1 Then
FirstTTID = JustificationMaxID
FirstATTID = AttachmentMaxID
End If


'Put Attachment File on the share drive ----------------------------------------
If IsNull(TempVars!SourceFile) = False Then
            destinationFile = TempVars!path & "AT\" & "" & FirstTTID & "" & "_" & "" & FirstATTID & "" & "_" & [Cisco] & "_" & _
            Day(Now) & "_" & Month(Now) & "_" & Year(Now) & "." & Right(TempVars!SourceFile, TempVars!FirstCommaPosition - 1)


con.Execute ("Update TBL_Attachment Set TBL_Attachment.Attachament_New_Path= '" & destinationFile & "'" _
           & "where TBL_Attachment.Attachament_Justification_ID=" & JustificationMaxID & "")
End If

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing

Justification_Date_Of_Case = Justification_Date_Of_Case + 1



If (Justification_Insert = 1) Then

         Set aFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         aFSO.CopyFile TempVars!SourceFile, destinationFile, True

         End If

Next Justification_Insert




MsgBox "Your Request Rasied Successfully !", vbInformation, "Successes"


Me.IDFrom = FirstTTID
Me.IDTO = JustificationMaxID

T1 = Justification_OT_Duration

'Clear Fields ##############################################################################################


TempVars.Remove ("SourceFile")
TempVars.Remove ("path")
TempVars.Remove ("FirstCommaPosition")
TempVars.Remove ("FileExt")

CommaPosition = Empty
vrtSelectedItem = Empty
destinationFile = Empty
aFSO = Empty
lenfile = Empty
lenreverse = Empty
FirstCommaPosition = Empty
FileExt = Empty
Me.SourceFile = Null

Justification_Cisco = Empty
Justification_Date_Of_Case = Empty
Justification_Move_Off = Empty
Justification_AgentShift = Empty
Justification_From = Empty
Justification_To = Empty
Justification_Credit_Hours = Empty
Justification_Debit_Hours = Empty
Justification_Justification = Empty
Justification_Description = Empty
Justification_Creator = Empty
Justification_Approved_By = Empty
Justification_Type = Empty
Justification_Group_ID = Empty
JustificationMaxID = Empty
AttachmentMaxID = Empty
FirstTTID = Empty
FirstATTID = Empty


 Set ParCisco = Nothing
 Set ParDate_Of_Case = Nothing
 Set ParMove_Off = Nothing
 Set ParAgentShift = Nothing
 Set ParFrom = Nothing
 Set ParTo = Nothing
 Set ParCredit_Hours = Nothing
 Set ParDebit_Hours = Nothing
 Set ParJustification = Nothing
 Set ParDescription = Nothing
 Set ParCreator = Nothing
 Set ParApproved_By = Nothing
 Set ParType = Nothing
 Set ParGroup_ID = Nothing
 Set ParFile_Ext = Nothing
 Set ParOriginal_Path = Nothing
 Set ParNew_Path = Nothing
 Set Justification_MaxID_OUT = Nothing
 Set ParAttachment_MaxID_Out = Nothing


 Me.Cisco = Null
 Me.JustificationType = Null
 Me.Just = Null
 Me.fromdate = Null
 Me.todate = Null
 Me.OldOff = Null
 Me.Approved = Null
 Me.Description = Null
 Me.FromEv = Null
 Me.ToEv = Null
 Me.AgentShift = Null



End Sub
```

and here is the SQL Server procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Justification_Insert]
    (
       @Justification_Cisco int
      ,@Justification_Date_Of_Case datetime
      ,@Justification_Move_Off datetime
      ,@Justification_AgentShift datetime
      ,@Justification_From datetime
      ,@Justification_To datetime
      ,@Justification_Event_Duration int
      ,@Justification_Credit_Hours int
      ,@Justification_Debit_Hours int
      ,@Justification_Justification varchar(60)
      ,@Justification_Description varchar(255)
      ,@Justification_Creator varchar(80)
      ,@Justification_Approved_By varchar(80)
      ,@Justification_Type varchar(40)
      ,@Justification_Group_ID int
      ,@Attachament_File_Ext nvarchar(10)
      ,@Attachament_Ori_Path nvarchar(255)
      ,@Attachament_New_Path nvarchar(255)
      ,@Justification_MaxID_OUT int out
      ,@Attachment_MaxID_Out int out
      )

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- insert into Justification --
    Insert Into [dbo].[TBL_Justification]
      (
       Justification_Cisco
      ,Justification_Date_Of_Case
      ,Justification_Move_Off
      ,Justification_AgentShift
      ,Justification_From
      ,Justification_To
      ,Justification_Event_Duration
      ,Justification_Credit_Hours
      ,Justification_Debit_Hours
      ,Justification_Justification
      ,Justification_Description
      ,Justification_Creator
      ,Justification_Approved_By
      ,Justification_Type
      ,Justification_Group_ID
      ,Justification_DT
      )

    values 
      (
       @Justification_Cisco
      ,@Justification_Date_Of_Case
      ,@Justification_Move_Off
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@Justification_AgentShift,108)
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@Justification_From,20)
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@Justification_To,20)
      ,@Justification_Event_Duration
      ,@Justification_Credit_Hours
      ,@Justification_Debit_Hours
      ,@Justification_Justification
      ,@Justification_Description
      ,@Justification_Creator
      ,@Justification_Approved_By
      ,@Justification_Type
      ,@Justification_Group_ID
      ,GETDATE()
      )

Set @Justification_MaxID_OUT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

 -- insert into WFM ID & Resolution --
    Insert Into TBL_WFM(
                        WFM_JustificationID
                       ,WFM_Resolution
                       ,WFM_Status)

          values (
                        @Justification_MaxID_OUT
                       ,'Open'
                       ,'Open');


 -- insert into WFM ID & Resolution --
    Insert Into TBL_attachment(
                   [Attachament_Justification_ID]
                  ,[Attachament_File_Ext]
                  ,[Attachament_Ori_Path]
                  ,[Attachament_New_Path]
                  ,[Attachament_DT])

          values( 
                  @Justification_MaxID_OUT
                 ,@Attachament_File_Ext
                 ,@Attachament_Ori_Path
                 ,@Attachament_New_Path
                 ,GETDATE())

Set @Attachment_MaxID_Out = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I would double check the sql connection is always being closed.  I suspect you are running out of available connections and that is why the restart solves your problem

Comment: I close the connection after excuting the prosedure,

Comment: In the sql server monitor tool i found alot of wiating time on the "network" figure when alot of users connect simaltaniously,  i think this is causing the problem, please advise